# Android BLE, Writing and Reading from the same device, without loss throughput and time

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, throughput

I'm currentily developing an application which uses Bluetooth Low Energy  to communicate with a BLE device. The problem is that the project require an high continuous exchange of data for working.

Currently i've developed 4 fragments which share the same BluetoothGatt istance and the same data array. When i connect to the BLE device, i set the connection priority to high, then i start a writing loop which writes the data, usually just 4 bytes, every 50 mls.

At the same time i start reading and i update my interface.
I've noticed that if i stop the writing i receive a packet of data  every 50 mls, but if i let the writing loop working the reading time increase from 50mls to 100 or more.
That's not a real big problem but it reduce all the sistem performances.

I looked on the internet for solutions but i didn't find nothing, except the connection priority that already helped me a lot, i'd like to know if someone have never managed such problems and how he did it. thanks

Comment: Using `write` and `read` on a `characteristic` is, somehow, a **heavy task** because it involves multiple radio signal exchanges to acknowledge data transfer. If you need to frequently send data, or to send a lot of data, I believe you need to use the **characteristic notification** system. It is meant to transfer data, as opposed to reading and writing for very occasional exchanges. Take a thermometer beacon: you'd want to be notified of temperature changes (instead of manually reading it) but you'd want to write to a characteristic to switch between F° and C° degrees for example. That's it !

Comment: After looking for documentation, here is the method you'd want to use :  [BluetoothGattServer#notifyCharacteristicChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html)

Comment: So are You suggesting to set the Characteristic value and then notify the change instead of set the value and call the writing? Sorry i just don't want to misunderstand, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, if you were to provide more information on what your app is supposed to do and what kind of data it needs to transfer, I could help more. But there is something I think I fail to understand: what device is supposed to send the data ? Is it the one that acts as a peripheral or central ? For example, which one has the 4 fragments. Because central mode devices are not supposed to send **a lot** of data. You could see like this: central => client, peripheral => server. You mostly download from a server, than upload to :).

Comment: However, should you need to upload data (e.g. an OTA firmware update for a BLE beacon), you can indeed upload to the peripheral, but it will be slow: you have to use the `write` and `read` process, and @darko-djuric 's point is right: the connection interval matters a lot. But the example I provided is rare and very occasional. The beacon would spend more time sending data rather than receiving it. So please, provide more info :)

Comment: I've got a Tablet which act as the central and a BLE peripheral devices (u can imagine it as an Arduino or a raspberry).  Both devices have to read and write in continious way to permit a safe real time update.   With the tablet, when i start a loop writing, the reading time decreases a lot

Comment: Alright. So your tablet must keep on sending data. I don't know why, but if it's mandatory, try the following idea. You can still use your loop but it will have to do, the following: write to the characteristic the desired value of 4 bytes, then **wait** for the write to be performed. The `onCharacteristicWrite` callback will be triggered to acknowledge the write. Then you can write again. Try with that first so it it works. For the wait part (**synchronized**), I suggest to use the lock / wait / notify mechanism since BLE is mostly **asynchronous** on Android.

Comment: Ok, i'll follow your advices, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Mackovich I don't se how this will reduce read time? Waiting for onCharacteristicWrite callback will not give option to read in a meantime.  "since BLE is mostly asynchronous on Android" Can you please explain this? If it is mostly asynchronous, when it is synchronous?

Comment: @DarkoDjuric well, this won't reduce read time, but it should keep a steady read time, and, thankfully enough, the fastest he can get form his devices. He won't be faster unless he can use notifyCharacteristicChange, but his tablet is in central mode. Now regarding the synchronous BLE, I said "mostly" because there are some method that are synchronous such as `BluetoothGatt#setCharacteristicNotification`, but yeah, the rest is asynchronous :)

Comment: @Mackovich What you have stated is wrong. Read time does not depend on way of writing so it will not be reduced or "steady". It is irrelevant if he is waiting for write callback or not. He still has to call readCharacteristic and waits for first available connection interval no mater what he was doing in write loop. Also, notifyCharacteristicChange would not speed up reading in this case since all connection intervals are spent on writing. For the rest of the things I would agree.

Comment: I agree with both of you two, this wont reduce reading time but at least i'll obtain the best performances i can obtain

Comment: @DarkoDjuric my bad, you are right, I forgot the read part. His problem is quite confusing, because I don't get what he tries to accomplish here ^^

Comment: @L.Gangemi I agree that write sequence should be done this way in order to avoid unnecessary write calls (which will be rejected anyway). Keep in mind that in callback solution will work only if characteristic that you use has write not write without response property set. And yes this will be the maximum you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE Device that you are using has something which is called "connection interval". It is set in firmware of device. Minimal value for it is 7.5ms, but usually is set to 30ms or more (iOS even will not work with intervals lower than 20-30ms or it will simply miss the packets).

So when BLE device firmware is designed, connection interval is set to some value which is safe and will work with most mobile devices, and also very important to save the battery.

Al this means that you can transfer to, or from device once per connection interval, no mater if it is read, write or notification.

Some devices has configuration settings which allows changing of connection interval, but if you just wanted to know what happens, thats it.

Comment: Ok, i understand this concept. I've already reduced the connection interval setting "Connection priority high" on my Android device. I just want to know how to avoid the connection interval time increasing while i read and write at the same time

Comment: This is something that you have done on yours Android device, but firmware still have its own value. Anyway, no mater of value, you can not avoid interval time increasing in this case. You can either read or a write in single connection interval. If you start to write, your read will be postponed for next free time slot (connection interval) and vice versa.

Comment: @L.Gangemi I am curious, how did you set the priority to high ? I'm interested !

Comment: Notifications and "write without response" are not restricted to one packet per connection interval. If you want to send much data fast from peripheral to central, use notifications. If you want to send much data fast from central to peripheral, use "write without response". You'll probably get somewhere between 4-12 packets in each direction per connection interval, depending on bluetooth chip inside phone.

Comment: @Emil I agree, but this would require access to device firmware if not already configured this way. Also, "Notifications and "write without response"" provides this possibility by sacrificing of acknowledgement. This increases throughput, but reduces reliability because there is no way of guaranteeing that the outgoing packets are received by the remote side, especially if pushed to the limits.

Comment: Just send un-acked packets first and end with one that is acked ;) the link layer sends them in order without drops so if the last arrives the other will too.

Comment: @Emil interesting theory. I must say that I haven't tried this way. This last one that has to be acked it must be sent on a different characteristic? Have you ever tested this? I will do, I promise ;-) I've tried a few times to push iPad up to the limits along with TI CC2540 and it was easy to create the drops even if connection interval was in custom range specified by Apple.

Comment: Yes. Apple doesn't like write without response. If the application sends them too fast Core Bluetooth drops them. A workaround can be to make sure each 12th packet or so is a write with response and the rest write without response. Then it doesn't seem to drop anything. Android's fine however since they have implemented flow control up to the application layer. What Apple does doesn't really seem to be explicitly allowed by the standard (the standard talks nothing about how system APIs should be constructed). Everything can be done on one characteristic if you declare the right permissions.